# NGINX rewrite www.example.com -> example.com

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I have a problem, this my rule:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    rewrite ^/(.*) http://example.com/$1 permanent;
}
```

But Firefox throws error : infinity bounce

I want rewrite www.example.com -> example.com

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this:

```
if ($host = 'www.domain.tld' ) {
   rewrite  ^/(.*)$  http://domain.tld/$1  permanent;
}
```

That way, only the "www." version will be rewritten

Alternative:

```
server {
   server_name www.domain.tld;
   rewrite ^ http://domain.tld$request_uri? permanent;
}
```

Comment: thanx you for help but it's not work... no rewrite. Test with Chromium and Firefox and cache clear.

Comment: ok, it's work only www.domaine.tld but it isn't work with for exemple: www.domaine.tld/cat/article/

Comment: Updated the answer with an alternative solution - have 2 `server` blocks, 1 for `domain.tld` and one like the above that rewrites

Comment: thanx but, I prefer a rewriting how apache2